# authorization failing with custom authentication scheme - asp.net-core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

i'm using:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("custom", options=> {
                options.LoginPath = "/admin/in";
                options.LogoutPath = "/admin/out";
            });
```

in `ConfigureServices` to register a custom authentication scheme.

when i try to use this scheme in my controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "custom")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

it simply redirects me to the login page even if the user is logged in and is in the correct role.

now if i change the `AuthenticationScheme` to be:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

everything works correctly and the user is authorized.

is there something i'm missing in the setup of the custom authentication scheme? how do i get my custom authentication scheme to work the same way `Identity.Application` does?

thanks

ps: i'm using asp.net core 3.0 preview 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that setting `options.ForwardAuthenticate = "Identity.Application";` solves this problem:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie("custom", options=> {
                options.LoginPath = "/admin/in";
                options.LogoutPath = "/admin/out";
                options.AccessDeniedPath= "/admin/in";
                options.ForwardAuthenticate = "Identity.Application";
            });

        }
```

this should really be documented